# TypeScript combination of function props with generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

The point of this Type is to allow user to pass in either **data, color, hasColor** or **data, info, hasInfo**. Not any other combination.

```
type Props = {
  data: string;
} & (
  | {
      info?: string;
      hasInfo?: boolean;
      color?: never;
      hasColor?: never;
    }
  | {
      info?: never;
      hasInfo?: never;
      color?: string;
      hasColor?: boolean;
    }
);


function foo(props: Props) {
  console.log("bar");
}

foo({ data: "hello", info: "hello", hasInfo: true }); <----- TypeScript is happy
foo({ data: "hello", info: "hello", hasColor: true }); <----- TypeScript gives Error
```

Is there a cleaner way to implement this behavior using generics?

I tried this, but it looks like I'm messing up the logic of the ternary somehow:

```
type Info = { info: string; hasInfo: boolean };
type Color = { color: string; hasColor: boolean };
type Data = { data: string };

function foo<T>(
  props: keyof T extends keyof Info ? Data & Info : Data & Color
) {
  console.log("bar");
}

foo({ data: "hello", color: "hello", hasColor: true }); <----TypeScript gives Error
```

The first way works but looks so ugly.

Comment: Both examples seem to work as expected. What is the issue here?

Comment: @TobiasS. the second example is not correct. It gives this error:
`Argument of type '{ data: string; color: string; hasColor: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Data & Info'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'color' does not exist in type 'Data & Info'.ts(2345)`

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/NBR04N) is a Playground of the first example. And [here](https://tsplay.dev/mbnqEm) one of the second. They both have an error on the second `foo` call. The error is slightly different, but I still don't see what you are expecting.

Comment: The point of the first Type is to allow user to pass in the function either `data, color, hasColor` or `data, info, hasInfo`. Not any other combination. I'm trying to achieve https://dev.to/maissenayed/conditional-react-props-with-typescript-43lg but with generics.

Comment: @TobiasS. [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgMwPZQLxQN5QJaKQLigGdgAnXAcwG4oALAQyPmUICMkkAbCeuKAXyoBYAFChIUAMJckpNJigBjGaUIlycanUbTOsth268BwseGgAResHrysAE2v01ZSidGiEAVziLg2JD5kJAAeABUAPgAKUSgoMFIkMCJCAGsIECQEKDCoCAAPYAg4eyIodMzs5hQAfigrGygAMlg8KEIG2xbdWVEASkxYpUCiLggAOj0KKIAiVnpSGb7Tfg8RTw4ohydCGdoITj0ZgBocPF39w6QT7SZzqDIvaH4+jaQtqEcbC4Oj09wWFA9r9rqcGEQeqoHqQngJXiJgh8vs4gZc-sM9FDgVcbuDIYRHs8+kA), I added a line to your second example

Comment: Definitely should be using overloads. Simpler and easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around I found another solid solution:

```
type Info = { info?: string; hasInfo?: boolean };
type Color = { color?: string; hasColor?: boolean };
type Data = { data: string };

function foo<T>(
  props: keyof Info extends keyof T
    ? Exclude<T, Color> & Data & Info
    : Exclude<T, Info> & Data & Color
) {
  console.log('bar');
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgMwPZQLxQN5QJaKQfgC4oBnYAJ1wHMBuKACwEMT5kioAjJJAGwkbhQAvjQCwAKFCQoAYV5JyaTFADG88uzKU4tBszk8F7Lr36CREqdAAijYIyVYAJncbEt1YWPESEAVzgVYGwkQWQkAB4AFQA%20AAoJKCgwciQwEmIAawgQJARYPCgIAA9gCDgnEihs3PyoxKSofCgAUWKVHj8nCGiAGll1GKgAMihbexGC5Aak4jaOrp6o-tYkIdHxh1GDBQkASkwGtTgSUwA6Qyo4gHIORnJrve8hCQkAejfgemwqknokPw8JxQBCMbA8XzcOIYBouezEa70CA8QzXXoNXDIBFIlFINENJgsPDECh%20CDo8RJQk7cgk8hkilJNSGWlQW6dCD48RCJ6vcQfL4-Uj-QHA0HgyFIaFQOFuNk41H9TFIbHIxV6IlYqCk8kaml0snCXk%20fmfb6-EVAkFgiHicLS2Wq3Fo1TqJ3qwmrA266lu7X06A87zvM1Cv4Aq3i2325yud14pXE%20VqhN6v06o3B02Ci0R4FgZgkSUOuPJ52JrWIlMuz1JjNBvkC80MPPJQvF2Pwsvq5kKeM1-TpgOZoA)

Answer (score 1):

With your current definiton, TypeScript is not able to infer the type parameter `T`, so it is inferred as `unknown` when calling the function. Therefore, `keyof T` is just `never` and the conditional always resolves to the false branch.

To fix this, we can intersect the result of the conditional with `T`.

```
function foo<T>(
  props: keyof Info extends keyof T 
    ? Data & Info & T 
    : Data & Color & T
) {
  console.log("bar");
}
```

Also note that we have to switch `keyof T extends keyof Info` to `keyof Info extends keyof T`. `keyof T` will be the larger union and therefore can't extend `keyof Info`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgMwPZQLxQN5QJaKQLigGdgAnXAcwG4oALAQyPmUICMkkAbCeuKAXyoBYAFChIUAMJckpNJigBjGaUIlycanUbTOsth268BwseGgAResHrysAE2v01ZSidGiEAVziLg2JD5kJAAeABUAPgAKUSgoMFIkMCJCAGsIECQEWDwoCAAPYAg4eyIodMzssKhYuKgAfigrGygAMhzkNqhq2rjCZtt23VkusNEASkxa5TgiLggAOj0KKIAiVnpSVfHTfg8RTw4ohydCVdoITj1VgBocPDOLq6Rb7SYHqDIvaH5xw6RjlBHDZHpdrndcCwoOcwS87gwiMNVJ9SN8BH8RMFAcDnNCnuClCpQc9XgikYQvj9xkA)